# image animation on screen

Tags: android, .net

I am trying to make an app where in the first screen, an image (name of the app) flies into the background, and gets fixed into a certain location. I am new to android and would appreciate any help.

I have tried using `setAnimationListener()`:

```
    public class Pageone extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    final ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    Animation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 1024, 824);
    anim1.setDuration(3000);
    anim1.setFillAfter(true);

    anim1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Animation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 824, 1024);
                    anim2.setDuration(3000);
                    anim2.setFillAfter(true);
                    imageView.clearAnimation();
                    imageView.startAnimation(anim2);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });


    imageView.startAnimation(anim1);


    }
    }
```

and the xml page as -

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.meeting.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:background="@drawable/tapregister" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/meet"
     />





    </RelativeLayout>'
```

While running the app in android virtual device manager, I find the image fixed as seen in the layout section.

Comment: What is happening with that code?

Comment: the image "meet" as being shown in the xml graphical layout with a still image in the center with no transition as i worked for is bieng shown when run on a android virtual device of eclipse..

Comment: Which ImageView do you want to animate? meet or image?

Comment: Sorry sir for a late reply ! Its like the app just starts up with an image in the background, kind of like a splash screen in which the image "meet" flies from the bottom of the screen to the center.

Comment: And right now the image just appears at the middle with no animation?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two animations to do what you want. You just need one animation that moves your ImageView from Bottom to the center of the screen.

So, drop your `anim1.setAnimationListener()` code. Change the Ydelta values to start in position Y+300 (for example) and end in position Y+0 (your layout original position). This will place your ImageView on the screen bottom, 300 px below your initial position and move it to the center, this is, to your layout initial position. Like this:

```
final ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
Animation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,300,0);
anim1.setDuration(3000);
anim1.setFillAfter(true);
imageView.startAnimation(anim1);
```